# python polars change value in filtered rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

how change from pandas to polars this:

```
self.df.loc[              
   (self.df['p23'] > z) &               
   (self.df['posn'] > 1) &                
   (self.df['ncL'] > y) ,             
   'tradeL'] = 1
```

```
┌────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┬────────┐
│ tms        ┆ p23      ┆ m23      ┆ posn ┆ ... ┆ ncL ┆ ncS ┆ tradeL ┆ tradeS │
│ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---  ┆     ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64        ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ i64  ┆     ┆ i32 ┆ i32 ┆ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 1667551500 ┆ 3.582475 ┆ 0.654813 ┆ 23   ┆ ... ┆ 16  ┆ 0   ┆ 0      ┆ 0      │
│ 1672989300 ┆ 2.727239 ┆ 1.510049 ┆ 31   ┆ ... ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 0      ┆ 0      │
│ 1673215200 ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0    ┆ ... ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0      ┆ 0      │
│ 1665506700 ┆ 0.236804 ┆ 4.000484 ┆ 0    ┆ ... ┆ 0   ┆ 26  ┆ 0      ┆ 0      │
│ ...        ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...  ┆ ... ┆ ... ┆ ... ┆ ...    ┆ ...    │
│ 1669979700 ┆ 0.437209 ┆ 3.800079 ┆ 6    ┆ ... ┆ 0   ┆ 13  ┆ 0      ┆ 0      │
│ 1669709700 ┆ 2.204868 ┆ 2.03242  ┆ 10   ┆ ... ┆ 12  ┆ 5   ┆ 0      ┆ 0      │
│ 1671648300 ┆ 3.27545  ┆ 0.961838 ┆ 30   ┆ ... ┆ 10  ┆ 0   ┆ 0      ┆ 0      │
│ 1668403800 ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0    ┆ ... ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0      ┆ 0      │
└────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┴────────┘
```

I not found, how to change value in the polars table. All example only show output.

I'm expecting something like this:

```
dfOut.select(
        pl.when((pl.col("p23")>2) 
             & (pl.col("posn")>1) 
            & (pl.col("ncL")>2)).then(dfOut["tradeL"]=1))

A | B | C | O
-----------
1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -> False
1 | 1 | 1 | ? | -> True <- column "O" & this row change value
1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | -> False

like this...

df["O"].when((A==1)&(B==1)&(C==1)).than(1).other(0)
```

QA: how to change in column O value, if all [A,B,C] is 1

SOLUTION (thanks jqurious):

```
df=df.with_columns(pl.when((pl.col("A")==1)& (pl.col("B")==1)& (pl.col("C")==1)).then(1).otherwise(pl.col("O")).alias("O"))
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal DataFrame with desired output?

Comment: When the condition is True you want the value 1 - otherwise you want the current value already in the column: `pl.when(...).then(1).otherwise(pl.col("tradeL"))`

Comment: No, i want to set  "tradeL" = 1 is when is true. My question is, how set value in the column if condition is true.

Comment: Sorry, yes - what I'm trying to say is in polars that is how you model it - you generate the values and "replace" the original column e.g. `.with_columns(pl.when(...).then(1).otherwise(pl.col("tradeL")).alias("tradeL")`

Comment: Thanks, this work ( but is not very intuitive  and is not in the documentation )

Comment: I had a look in the documentation and found https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html?highlight=modify#column-assignment-based-on-predicate - do you think that explains what you're trying to do?